# How can a backdrop be added for any component using Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-components

I would like to add a backdrop to the page so that when a component on the page is in "edit mode", only that component is accessible to the user.

I know I can achieve this with a modal dialog, but I want the component to remain in its original position and darken/disable everything else on the page.

Is this possible using Angular Material? Maybe using the CDK?